# Dynamic Memory Allocation in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, managed-c++

What is the difference between the 'delete' and 'dispose' C++ operators with regards to dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: Do you mean Dispose with CLI & Disposable objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delete` will free memory dynamically allocated in unmanaged C++
`Dispose` will force custom object implemented maintenance of disposable objects in managed C++/CLI

Answer (score 3):

There's no `dispose` operator (or standard function, or anything of that ilk) in standard C++ -- are you thinking of some specific proprietary framework, such as Microsoft's .NET "managed C++"?  `delete` **is** standard, it's indeed an operator, and must behave [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_(C%2B%2B)) in any standard conforming implementation -- that's the main difference with operator `dispose`, and also the main difference with operators `unicorn`, `toothfairy`, and `santaclaus`, which have a lot in common since none of those **exists**!-)  [[Sorry Virginia...!]]

Comment: lol... top answer, just to add Dispose is a hack of a hack and only forced onto the air-contaminated Redmond designers back in 2000/1 when they finally listened to the community and introduced a pattern and later a keyword.But it was too late and few years following they started bloating everything Java fmrk style,most glaring example being in service and UI tech.Good that they realised 'unmanaged' resources are all that actually exists in the physical, computing and other galaxies across the universe. Alas, some things never change,despite a moment or two of humble listening at c#@msdn.com..

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is related to .NET managed C++ because standard C++ has no sense of "dispose".

Delete will release the memory used to store the object; this memory returns to the heap and can be used for other storage requirements.

Dispose will give the object the chance to release resources it acquired such as file handles, etc. Standard C++ would see this sort of task done in the destructor.